# How to merge each list item with async operation result using RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have `List<News>` - list with my news. I must make async request for each news for get news images list (from API).

I try make it using RxJava - but I can't make it(

I think use for that `Observable.fromIterable(newsList)` and then use `zipWith(imagesListRequestObservalbe, News, News(with images))` and then `toList()` but how it make in code - i dont know.

Please tell me how to resolve my problem using **RxJava**?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like following:

```
Observable.from(newsList)
  .flatMap(newsItem -> getImageList(newsItem))
  .toList()
  .subscribe(..)
```

Comment: Thank you but how to merge imagesList with relevant news item?

Comment: You can use `Pair.create()` in `flatMap()`